# Filter through column using if statements to calculate new cell value. VALUEERROR:

Tags: python

```
angle_rad = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(X)):
    if ((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i]) <0 and (X-track.Doublewide_x[i]) <0).all:
        angle_rad.append(math.atan((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i])/(X-track.Doublewide_x[i])))
    elif ((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i]) <0 and (X-track.Doublewide_x[i]) >=0).all:
        angle_rad.append(math.pi - math.atan((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i])/(X-track.Doublewide_x[i])))
    elif ((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i]) >=0 and (X-track.Doublewide_x[i]) >=0).all:
        angle_rad.append(math.atan((Y-track.Doublewide_y[i])/(X-track.Doublewide_x[i]))+math.pi)
```

This is the loop I created in my script. I am trying to filter through a dataset and alter the values based on the conditions in this loop. When I run it, I get the Error:

'''
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or
a.all().
'''

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have an multidimensional array. so you should compare each value separately in if condition. for example your array might be `x = [ [1,-2,3],[-4,5,6] ]` so when comparing you should check each of them being positive or negative.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        if x[i][j] > 0:
            do something here
```